# Why my ThreadPool isn't running in parallel in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpoolexecutor

I'm implementing database connections for my mobile game.

I've created a connection pool (it works for sure) and a thread pool like below:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
```

I run tasks only once like this at the start:

```
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                queryDatabase();
            }
        }, 0, 300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

My `queryDatabase()` method looks like this:

```
private void queryDatabase(){

    List<DataBaseQuery> queriesToExecute = new LinkedList<>();

    if(queries.drainTo(queriesToExecute, 3) == 0){
        queriesToExecute.add(queries.take());
    }

    for(DataBaseQuery query: queriesToExecute) {
        query.executeQuery(); 
    }
}
```

`executeQuery()` is an interface method which I implement in code and it looks like:

```
@Override
public void executeQuery(){
    // get connection from the pool

    System.out.println("query 1");
    doFirstQuery(); // do first query (20-100ms) for ex. check if user already exists. Function will block for 20-100ms

    System.out.println("query 2");
    // do second query (20-100ms) for ex. check if email exists

    System.out.println("query 3");
    // do third query (20-100ms) for ex. insert new user

}
```

**My test case:**
I put 100 same `executeQuery()` methods into queriesToExecute BlockingQueue. ThreadPool should drain 3 executeQuery() on each thread and execute methods in parallel.

**What happens?**

I always get the output in this order (bigger output of course):

```
query 1
query 2
query 3
query 1
query 2
query 3
```

which means that tasks are not fired in parallel. If they were run in parallel, I would get 'random' System.out order right?

Am I doing something wrong? My processor is Intel Core i5 with 4 worker threads. I use ThreadPool for the first time.

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Do you have only one task in your threadpool?

Comment: I call `scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate` only once at the beginning of the application. Is this wrong? I thought it should just run 5 threads and each of this thread will call queryDatabase(); every 300ms.

Comment: No, a threadpool doesn't run a single task on multiple threads. You can have a lot of tasks in one pool and the pool will run X of them concurrently where X is the number of threads, however a single task will never run concurrently. See [scheduleAtFixedRate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))  `If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.`

Comment: I read it but somehow I didn't see this part. Oh my god. Thanks. Do you have any clue how to call `queryDatabase()` in parallel by 5 different threads?

Comment: @Spectre create 5 different instances of Runnable with calls to queryDatabase() and submit them all to the thread pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only scheduling one task to your Scheduler. So this task is always executed sequentially. You could try scheduling the same task multiple times.

The `newScheduledThreadPool` parameter only specifies how many Threads to keep alive even if nothing is to be executed. This is more or less a performance tweaking parameter.

Comment: Why to use newScheduledThreadPool then? :D Ok. Now I get it all. But what should I use to make parallel calls to `queryDatabase()` by 5 different threads?

Comment: Just copy & paste your scheduleAtFixedRate line, or put it into a for loop.